# Execute a Go programm (webcrawler) as a cron job on Google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go, cron, web-crawler

How can I run a single Go program namend "gcinfo" (webcrawler with output in firebase) as a cron in Google appengine?

I was able to create a projekt-ID and upload the Go programm with the App SDK. The cron job was executed   as defined in the cron.yaml every 15 minutes. There was no error. But i find no output in the log and firebase ist not written. After lots of changes in the app.yaml, gcinfo.yaml and cron.yaml with no result or Errors like (Error code 204). I am now totally confused about the settings in the yaml-files.

Can someone give or point me to a simple example of these settings? I want to run a single Go program as a cron in the app engine every 15 minutes.

My projekt structur is:

- myproject folder with app.yaml and cron.yaml
- myproject subfolder "hello" with hello.yaml and the simple hello.go example with "hello world!"
- myproject subfolder "gcinfo" with gcinfo.yaml and gcinfo.go (go webcrawler with firebase-output)"

app.yaml

```
application: myproject
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: Ausfuehrung des tasks gcinfo
url: /gcinfo
schedule: every 15 minutes from 05:30 to 23:00
timezone: Europe/Berlin
target: gcinfo
```

gcinfo.yaml

```
application: myproject
module: gcinfo
#version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /gcinfo\.*
script: gcinfo\gcinfo.go
```

My gcinfo.go has the following structure

```
package gcinfo

import (
...
)

....

func gcinfo() {
....
}
```

There are no errors with this configuration in the "goapp deploy" and the appengine reacts every 15 minutes for 6ms, but there is no output for the go programm gcinfo. I have already tryed to make gcinfo to main with same result.

Comment: Please don't ask for code examples. It's better if you include your relevant code directly into the question. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution and now the cron job runs and writes comments in the Job Control.

cron.yaml in myproject folder

```
cron:
- description: Ausfuehrung des tasks gcinfo
url: /gcinfo
schedule: every 15 minutes from 05:30 to 23:00
timezone: Europe/Berlin
```

app.yaml in the subfolder gcinfo

```
application: myproject
module: gcinfo
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /gcinfo
  script: _go_app
```

and the key changes in gcinfo.go (gcinfo subfolder)

```
package gcinfo

import (
"net/http"
...
"appengine"
"appengine/urlfetch"
)

func init() {
 http.HandleFunc("/gcinfo", gcinfo)
}
...

func gcinfo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
...
}
```

Only writing firebase engine does not work with the appengine. I'll have to do more research.